# How to fetch Django models objects/queryset as dictionary in case of multiple levels of relationship?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    population = models.BigIntegerField()

class State(models.Model):
    state_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    population = models.BigIntegerField()

class District(models.Model):
    state_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    population = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Now given a `country_id`, I want to fetch all the related `State` and `District`  in following format:

```
{
    'country':{
        'country_id': 1,
        'coutry_population': 120000,
        'state':[
            {
            'state_id': 10,
            'state_name': 'A',
            'state_population': 10000,
            'district':[
                {
                    'district_id': 100,
                    'district_name': 'District1',
                    'district_population': 4000
                },
                {
                    'district_id': 101,
                    'district_name': 'District2',
                    'district_population': 6000
                }]
            },
            {
                <2nd state data here>
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also I should be able select particular columns from each of the model.

> For Eg: Only `state_name` from `State` Model, `district_name` and `district_population` from `District` Model, etc

I also need the feature of filtering, at different models.

> For eg: Only get districts matching condition district.population >
>   5000

None of the question I could find here helped to solve the problem. Closest one seemed to be this :
[Django: Most efficient way to create a nested dictionary from querying related models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626867/django-most-efficient-way-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-querying-related-m)

But here the relationship is in opposite direction.

One solution I could think of was to query each of the models differently, and store them in dictionary, and combine later. But if I could get more of a direct approach, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually glue together a dictionary with the required data.

You can query the country object and get the the related districts through the related manager.

```
my_country = Country.objects.get(1)
all_districts = my_country.district_set.all()
```

Or filtered districts:

```
filtered_districts = my_country.district_set.filter(district_name='...')
```

You can also set a related_name in the Model class eg:

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'states')
    population = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Then you can query the related states with:

`large_states_of_my_country = my_country.states.filter(population_gte = 50000)`

See:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name

Comment: This is certainly helpful. But even with this, I cannot get the data in the structure I want right ? I need the dictionary in structure  `country->state->district` as mentioned in question. This query will give me all the districts under the country. But I want it all state-wise. And also some data from state table, as shown in the example in question.

Comment: There is another related manager for the state objects. So if you need to access all the districts for a given state you can just do state.district_set.all(). E.g. `for state in large_states_of_my_country: districts_of_state = state.district_set.all() ...`